# ¿Cómo podría sumar los valores de esta consulta?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

¿Cómo podria sumar los valores de esta consulta con la función `sum ()`?

Me gustaría sumarlos para mostrar el total de los puntos obtenidos.

```
SELECT IF(p.ganador = no_equi,'3',IF(p.ganador = 'Empate','1','0')) AS total_puntos FROM partidos p
INNER JOIN equipos l ON p.num_eqpo_loc = l.num_eqpo 
INNER JOIN equipos v ON p.num_eqpo_vis = v.num_eqpo
WHERE l.nom_equipo = no_equi OR v.nom_equipo = no_equi;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria de la siguiente manera utilizando la función SUM()

```
SELECT SUM(IF(p.ganador = no_equi,'3',IF(p.ganador = 'Empate','1','0'))) AS total_puntos FROM partidos p
INNER JOIN equipos l ON p.num_eqpo_loc = l.num_eqpo 
INNER JOIN equipos v ON p.num_eqpo_vis = v.num_eqpo
WHERE l.nom_equipo = no_equi OR v.nom_equipo = no_equi;
```